Samsung SM-P900 - won't turn on, no leds, charging has no effect
I was asked by a friend to try to get an (abandoned?) Samsung SM-P900 tablet into working order.

(This is not my device, just an illustration.)
The device does not exhibit any physical damage, and only has a bit of wear on the silvery bezel. The stylus is missing though.
The tablet has a Micro-B SuperSpeed socket (thin, wide, indented in the middle), so I'm trying to charge it with a cable from a WD Elements I have, which is USB-A on one side and USB-B Micro SuperSpeed on the other. It's been charging for a while already - but I see nothing on screen, nor a LED light up. Pressing the power button for a few seconds also does nothing.
Questions:

Is my cable choice "legit", or should I try charging some other way?
Is there something else I can do, other than look for some technician, to bring the tablet back to life?
Can this behavior indicate battery failure, as opposed to another kind of hardware failure?
Is it likely that the tablet is simply full-dead and I shouldn't bother with it?


AFIR for charging you shouldn't need an super speed cable. The regular smaller micro B plug should also fit. There are some videos available showing how to replace the battery. On a different Samsung tablet of that age I was able to revive it by disconnecting the battery and then start the tablet with charger connected. The battery connector seems to be accessible without too much problems so you could give it a try and you have nothing to lose.

@Robert: I would make that an answer.

tl;dr: First, try charging it for a longer while.
(This is not the only possible answer, but:) as I didn't have anything else to do with it for now, I just let it go on charging. After about... 2.5 hours or so, I pressed the multifunction button, and the screen came up with a charge indicator of 10%. So, an overnight (or even 24h ?) charging session should probably do the trick.
It may also be that the battery is quick to discharge or is otherwise damaged, so you may end up having to replace it. But - maybe not, who knows.
